# Powershell script in Jenkins groovy shared library

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy

I'm following the Jenkins guide on how to use [shared libraries](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#using-libraries), but when I try to replace the bash shell script with Powershell, I'm unable to access the script argument.

I have attempted every combination of groovy string replacement I can think of, combined with Powershell's use of variables, but none of them can access the argument.

All of the examples in this script, write an empty argument result:

```
def call(String argument) {
    powershell '''
        $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
                    
        try
        {
            Write-Output "First=$argument."
            Write-Output "Second=${argument}"
            Write-Output "Third=$($argument)"
            Write-Output "Fourth=${$(argument)}"
            Write-Output "Fifth=$env:argument"
            Write-Output "Sixth=${env:argument}"
            Write-Output "Seventh=${$env:argument}"
            Write-Output "Eights=$($env:argument)"
            Write-Output "Ninths=\$argument"
            Write-Output "Tenth=\${argument}"
            Write-Output "Eleventh=(${argument})."
            Write-Output "Twelvth=${params.argument}"
            Write-Output "Thirteenth=\${params.argument}"
            Write-Output "Fourteent=${argument}"
        }
        catch
        {
            # Write the received error to the error output.
            Write-Output $Error[0]
                        
            #Return an error code.
            Exit 1
        }
    '''
}
```

Can anyone tell me which syntax to use, to get Powershell to write the `argument` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`withEnv`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables) to set environment variables in the given scope, which can be used directly from shell scripts, e. g. in PowerShell by using the `$env:VariableName` syntax and in Bash by using the `$VariableName` syntax.

```
def call(String argument) {

    withEnv([ "myArg1=$argument" ]) {
    
        powershell '''
            $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

            Write-Output "First=$env:myArg1"
        '''
    }
}
```

**Note:**
For security reasons it is recommended to avoid Groovy string interpolation, when passing arguments to a shell script ([detailed explanation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#interpolation-of-sensitive-environment-variables)).